# KnockoutJS make change event trigger when I update a select UI programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
<select class="form-control" 
    data-bind="attr: {name: 'id_' + $index(), id:'id_' + $index()},
               event:{ change:$parent.Collect}">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select a date to collect from</option>
    <option data-bind="attr:{value:$data.DeliveryDate},
                       value="09/28/2018">Friday 28 September</option>
</select>
```

Ok so I've a task to programmatically update a select for an AB test, something i've done many times e.g.

```
$('.form-control').val('09/28/2018').change();
```

This updates the UI but doesn't seem to call the change event which is on the knockout bindings. I cannot update the source code and need to find a way to do it in my AB tool.

My knockout knowledge is very limited, I've installed the devtool for knockout and I've tried looking in the bindings by passing a context but I cannot figure out if its even possible to get the `$parent.Collect` method to execute.

Any help is really appreciated...

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think you can trigger the Knockout change event when `select` doesn't even have the [value binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a value data-binding to the select. If that doesn't resolve the problem, remove $parent form change ($parent.Collect) event in the select element. "selectedValue" is a observable in the view model. Handle the selectedValue observable inside the Collect function.

```
<select class="form-control" 
    data-bind="attr: {name: 'id_' + $index(), id:'id_' + $index()},
               value: selectedValue, event:{ change:$parent.Collect}">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select a date to collect from</option>
    <option data-bind="attr:{value:$data.DeliveryDate},
                       value="09/28/2018">Friday 28 September</option>
</select>
```